# Django - NOT NULL constraint failed and WSGIRequest error

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm making a store type site with Django and currently working on a review and rating system. My 'reviews' app includes a Model called 'Review' and a view for adding a review from the product description template. The model:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    rating = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The problem I'm having is that the view isn't passing the product_id field, which results in a NOT NULL constraint failed error. That view is as below:

```
@login_required
def add_review(request):

    if request.user:
        if request.method == "POST":
            review_form = ReviewForm(request.POST)
            if review_form.is_valid():
                review = review_form.save(commit=False)
                review.author = request.user
                review_form.save()

                messages.success(request, "Review posted successfully!")
                return redirect(reverse(get_reviews))
        else:
            review_form = ReviewForm()
    else:
        messages.error(request, "You must be a member to post reviews.")
        return redirect(reverse(get_reviews))

    args = {'review_form': review_form}
    return render(request, "add_review.html", args)
```

However, when I try and rectify that by using the same method to pass the author (which I know works as I've used that code elsewhere), I get a WSGIRequest error stating that "object has no attribute 'product' ". The added line seen below:

```
            ...
            if review_form.is_valid():
                review = review_form.save(commit=False)
                review.product = request.product
                review.author = request.user
                review_form.save()
                ...
```

As may be glaringly obvious, but my Django knowledge is somewhat limited as I'm still in the process of learning it. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I've been asked to share the urls.py, so here it is:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import review_content, add_review, edit_review, delete_review

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', review_content, name='review-content'),
    url(r'^add-review/$', add_review, name='add-review'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', edit_review, name='edit-review'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/delete-review/$', delete_review, name='delete- 
                                                              review'),
]
```

Comment: There is no `request.product`. Where are you expecting that to be coming from?

Comment: Show your urls. Looks like you need to get the product id from request.GET.

Comment: Urls.py has been added as an edit